# How to insert data using a procedure with restrictions

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I have a table in which I want to be able to add scheduled data into. This involves a code as a the PK and a room with a date. I want the restriction to involve only being able to add a new row of data with a code room and date that is at minimum a month away and be only scheduled for working days.

I've tried simplistic statements to inserting the data, and there's a lot of ways to doing this from what I've found. But I think I'm in a the black hole zone for this where everything I'm finding, I'm not understanding the information that is given to me. If you could help be figure what I should be doing to not get my stuck in the future.

```
CREATE TABLE session(
code CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
date DATE NOT NULL, 
room VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT pri_session PRIMARY KEY (code));

INSERT INTO session(code, date, room)
    VALUES('202B', '2020.05.03', 303);

DELIMITER &&

CREATE PROCEDURE assign_schedual (IN code char(4), IN date DATE, IN room VARCHAR(30))
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT code FROM session;

        OPEN c;

        CLOSE c;

    END&&

DELIMITER ;
```

I expect the ability to use the procedure to ensure dates answered are a month in advanced, and are on working days only.

An example of the sample data: 403B, 2019.10.02, 303

Would deny the insert due to the date being not a minimum a month away and being in a weekend.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is valid data?  What is not valid data?

Comment: The data I'm wanting to insert would be a code with 4 characters (business decision e.g. 202B) a full date including year.month.day and a 3 digit room number represented by a number. Does this help this understanding?

Comment: I want the data to be validated against the date, to be a month away minimum from current date and for the date to only be within working days (not saturdays and sundays)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
   Begin

     IIF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( 
      SELECT 
      code FROM 
     session where
     sysdate() -date >30 and  
      DAYNAME(date) not like 'S%') >1)
      THEN
     ..... 
     ELSE  
     //discard data.. 
     End IF
     End
```

Comment: I think this would only retrieve the data I already have? I want this procedure to validate the input of data... I'm fairly new to MySQL correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I guess if you want to prevent insert then you must go for trigger as trigger is action dependent so whenever the insert would be made on a particular table the associated trigger before insert would become active so as to validate as well as prevent the insertion or if you just want to validate you can workaround with the above sample posted with if else condition

Comment: Can you insert data through a procedure?

Comment: Obeviously yes.